# pgfplots - How can I address the coordinates of a plot's title in a groupplot?

Tags: pgfplots

Say I provide a title to a groupplot via

```
title={Word}
```

Is there a way to address the area of this node, e.g. via `.north west` and so on (as detailed on page 314 in the manual)?

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: by addressing you mean placing the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `title=something`, what is inserted is something like `\node [every axis title] {something};`. You can add node names with the `name=` option, so you can modify the `every axis title` style to add a name for the title node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}]
\nextgroupplot[title=Stuff,every axis title/.append style={name=title1}]
\addplot {x^2};

\nextgroupplot[title=More Stuff,every axis title/.append style={name=title2}]
\addplot {x^3};
\end{groupplot}

\draw (title1.north east) to[out=45,in=135] (title2.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```